# extend a angular component with ng-template

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using Kendo Ui as my favorite Ui Framework for Angular.

```html
<kendo-multiselect [data]="listItems" [(ngModel)]="value">
       <ng-template kendoMultiSelectHeaderTemplate let-dataItem>
            <strong (click)="toggleSelection()">Alle Auswählen</strong>
         </ng-template>
</kendo-multiselect>
```

So far so good, but I need the ng-template an more in nearly every of my multiselect dropdownlists. So my question is, can I create a directive which I can use directly on the host komponent which creates me the ng-template and all the other stuff I need or what is here the best solution to extend a existing component subtemplate.

example result:

```html
<kendo-multiselect my-multiselectHeader 
                   [data]="listItems" 
                   [(ngModel)]="value">
</kendo-multiselect>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Solution seems to be easier than I thought before.

I create a new surrounding directive where I can access the

- ContentChild => is the multiselect component where we have access to all properties
- ViewChild => is the Headertemplate I want to assign to the multiselect

with this solution I can access all natural properties from the original multiselect and I only extend the functions I "need" with the help from ng-content

sq-multiselect-extension.html:

```
<ng-template kendoMultiSelectHeaderTemplate let-dataItem>
   <strong (click)="toggleSelection()" class="m-2 link-cursor">Alle Auswählen</strong>
</ng-template>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

sq-multiselect-extension.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ContentChild } from    '@angular/core';
import { HeaderTemplateDirective, MultiSelectComponent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns'
@Component({
    selector: 'sq-multiselect-extension',
    templateUrl: './sq-multiselect-extension.html',
})
export class SxpMultiselectComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(HeaderTemplateDirective) headerTemplate: HeaderTemplateDirective;
    @ContentChild(MultiSelectComponent) multiselect: MultiSelectComponent;

public ngOnInit() {
  this.multiselect.headerTemplate = this.headerTemplate;
}

public toggleSelection(): void {
  if (this.multiselect.value.length > 0) {
    this.multiselect.reset();
  }
  else {
     this.multiselect.writeValue(this.multiselect.data)
     this.multiselect.value = this.multiselect.data.slice();
  } 
 }
}
```

and to use this new component

```
<sq-multiselect-extension>
    <kendo-multiselect [data]="listStringItems" [(ngModel)]="value" class="form-control">
    </kendo-multiselect>
</sq-multiselect-extension>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this isn't a big deal. It only depends on what you want to do but creating a directive to customize header doesn't seems to be too hard to do.

I think you can play with `ng-template` injection and / or using of [`ngTemplateOutlet`](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/#dynamictemplatecreationwiththengtemplateoutletdirective).

But I suggest you to take a look at the `kendoMultiSelectHeaderTemplate` directive to check what it does precisely.

If you're using the `let-dataItem` variable, check you can use it anyway on your custom `Directive`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to reuse the multiselect input, I would suggest wrapping the kendo element into a separate component. This way, if you will ever need to pass some custom options to the kendo element, you can do it in one place and it will affect all multiselects.

Comment: here is the problem, that I have to wrap through all kendo dropdown functions and when I only need one specific feature I have to wrap a new component, my favorite solution would be to create some specific directives, which handle e.g. the header template, ....

Comment: You could pass a property to the wrapped kendo component with the desired feature name, and inside the component template you could do a ngSwitch to render the template.

`<my-kendo-dropdown [template]="feature1"></my-kendo-dropdown>`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to squadwuschel's answer, this works perfect for me using `Angular 8`

I have extended Kendo MultiSelect component with `Select All` functionality

In `ngOnInit` the component is not yet rendered so you will get it as undefined. So you gotta use `AfterViewInit`

> multiselect-extended.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  Output,
  ContentChild,
  AfterViewInit,
  EventEmitter
} from "@angular/core";
import {
  HeaderTemplateDirective,
  MultiSelectComponent
} from "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns";

@Component({
  selector: "app-custom-multselect",
  templateUrl: "./custom-multselect.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./custom-multselect.component.css"]
})
export class CustomMultselectComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(HeaderTemplateDirective, { static: false })
  headerTemplate: HeaderTemplateDirective;
  @ContentChild(MultiSelectComponent, { static: false })
  multiselect: MultiSelectComponent;

  @Output() selectAllEvent: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.multiselect);
    this.multiselect.headerTemplate = this.headerTemplate;
  }

  public toggleSelection(): void {
    if (this.multiselect.value.length > 0) {
      this.multiselect.reset();
      this.selectAllEvent.emit(false);
    } else {
      this.multiselect.writeValue(this.multiselect.data);
      this.multiselect.value = this.multiselect.data.slice();
      this.selectAllEvent.emit(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that i have added a `selectAllEvent` to update the checkboxes shown inside the multiselect dropdown.

> app.component.html

```html
<app-custom-multselect (selectAllEvent)=" selectAllItems($event)">
    <kendo-multiselect [data]="listItems" [(ngModel)]="value" [textField]="'text'" [valueField]="'value'"
        [autoClose]="false">
        <ng-template kendoMultiSelectItemTemplate let-dataItem>
            <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox"
          [checked]="isItemSelected(dataItem.text) || isAllSelected">
            <label class="k-checkbox-label">{{ dataItem.text }}</label>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-multiselect>
</app-custom-multselect>
```

> app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  public listItems: Array<{ text: string; value: number }> = [
    { text: "Small", value: 1 },
    { text: "Medium", value: 2 },
    { text: "Large", value: 3 },
    { text: "XL", value: 4 },
    { text: "XXL", value: 5 }
  ];
  public value: any = [];
  public isAllSelected: boolean = false;

  public isItemSelected(itemText: string): boolean {
    return this.value.some(item => item.text === itemText);
  }

  selectAllItems(isSelectAll) {
    if (isSelectAll) {
      this.isAllSelected = true;
    } else {
      this.isAllSelected = false;
    }
  }
}
```

You can also find the demo here on [StackBlitz](https://angular-kendo-multiselect-selectall.stackblitz.io)